# How can I trigger a function on a div returned after an Ajax form is submitted by a partial view returned by my controller action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have in my view an Ajax form which is submitted when a button is clicked, this is the form and the div it updates:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("finalstatus", "User", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "end-popup",
    OnSuccess = "popupappear()"
}, new { id = "progForm"}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.SectionID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.CourseID)
}
<div id="end-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide"></div>
```

The function called by onsuccess is as follows:

```
function popupappear() {
    $('.popup-end').magnificPopup({
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        //preloader: false,
        items: {
            src: '#end-popup',
            type: 'inline'
        },
        midClick: true
    });
}
```

The controller action called by the submission of the form is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult finalstatus(SubSectionViewModel model)
{
    string currentuser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var viewModel = db.enrollment
        .Where(i => i.UserID == currentuser)
        .Where(i => i.course.CourseID == model.CourseID)
        .Select(x => new CurrentProgressViewModel
        {
            ovpcnt = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * x.progress.Sum(c => c.progress)) / x.course.course_sections.SelectMany(i => i.course_subsections).Sum(c => c.scenes)),
        }).Single();
    return PartialView("_endofsection", viewModel);
}
```

The controller action returns the partial view, then the function will make it visible as a popup for the user.  My issue is that this does not occur on the first click, but works fine on any following clicks.

I have tried replacing the onsuccess function with alert('success') and the function does fire on the first click.

My question is how do I orchestrate things so that the function is run after the partial view has been returned by my controller on the first click?

Thanks for any help.

edit - As Stephen Muecke has informed me the onsuccess function should fire after the page has been updated I have removed from my original post my assumption that this wasn't the case.

Comment: `OnSuccess` runs after the page has been updated so that is not your issue.

Comment: ok thank you, do you have any idea why it does not seem to run correctly on the first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, it was with the jquery plugin magnific popup, I had to chain the open method for this plugin after I initialised it in the function.  So my function became:

```
function popupappear() {
$('.popup-end').magnificPopup({
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    //preloader: false,
    items: {
        src: '#end-popup',
        type: 'inline'
    },
    midClick: true
}).magnificPopup('open');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` property should be set without the parenthesis.

Also make sure that your success function is defined from the start.

If not, check in the console if you are getting any errors.